# C++ member functions with different behavior defined at initialization

Tags: c++, function, class, member

Suppose I have a class, like:

```
template<class TYPE>
class RandomAccessBox {
      //...
  public:
    void insert (TYPE x){
      //insert something into the box
    }
    int size(){
      //return number of elements in the box
    }
    TYPE randomaccess(){
      //return random object in the box
    }
    TYPE deletelast(){
      //delete last item accessed from the box
    }
};
```

I have program that uses a RandomAccessBox all over the place.

Suppose now that I want some runtime specialization.  That is, when initialize my RandomAccessBox, I want to set it to type 1 or type 2, let's say (and the type will never change).  The functions and members of the class will be the same for both types, but I want to be able to simply change the behavior of the functions depending on the type.  (For example, perhaps I want to change how things are stored and randomly accessed).

The point is that I don't want the rest of the code to have to care about which type of RandomAccessBox I have, since the publically facing functions and members will be the same, and the two types are used in the same way.

In particular, I want to be able to have functions like

```
void statisticsonbox(RandomAccessBox mybox){
  //do some stuff with mybox
}
```

which are agnostic to the type of mybox.

Obviously I could have an internal variable storing the type and then have each function case based on the status of this variable.  This RandomAccessBox is "in the inner loop", though, so any penalty associated with that is a problem.  (Perhaps realistically there is essentially no penalty from casing like this with modern processors?)

I could also use function pointers.

Is there another way that this is supposed to be done?

Comment: are you looking for polymorphism via inheritance? ie same interface but different implementations

Comment: I think you're just looking for a base class with pure `virtual` public functions.

Comment: If the behavior is determined at runtime, it must be the same type. Which doesn't leave you many options besides the one that's exactly as what you described, or logically equivalent to it.

Comment: @Quentin, virtual fuctions will require interface matching, for example instead `TYPE randomaccess()` will need to use something like `void* randomaccess()`, which is very bad. Or are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

> This RandomAccessBox is "in the inner loop", though, so any penalty
>   associated with that is a problem. (Perhaps realistically there is
>   essentially no penalty from casing like this with modern processors?)

You need to use templates for the whole part of the code that depends on `RandomAccessBox`. F.e.:

```
template <class TYPE>
void statisticsonbox(RandomAccessBox<TYPE> mybox){
  //do some stuff with mybox
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to somehow determine the behavior at each iteration (using virtual methods, type determining and branching etc), which will inevitably cause a loss of performance (if this is really important in your case). Such an approach can cause problems - an increase in compilation time, output file size, changing a significant part of the code to use templates. You need to separate the type dependent and independent parts and choose the optimal ratio.

Comment: I should have clarified: The TYPE in the template here will (or may) be the same in the various "types" of RandomAccessBoxes.